# Can't run ansible command on remote host with sudo: Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

My ansible ad-hoc command runs fine as an user, but fails when the same command is run with sudo.

```bash
[ansible@tower ansible-automation-platform-setup-bundle-2.3-2.1]$ ansible all -m ping
tower.vmnet.local | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
[ansible@tower ansible-automation-platform-setup-bundle-2.3-2.1]$ sudo ansible all -m ping
tower.vmnet.local | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ansible@tower.vmnet.local: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

My `ansible.cfg` contains:

```bash
[defaults]
inventory = inventory
remote_user = ansible
host_key_checking = false

[privilege_escalation] 
become = True
become_method = sudo
become_user = root
become_ask_pass = False
```

Can't figure out why this is. Root login is permitted in /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```bash
[ansible@tower ansible-automation-platform-setup-bundle-2.3-2.1]$ sudo cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep Root
PermitRootLogin yes #prohibit-password
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're mixing up some things. The results you got makes perfect sense because you're running the second command as *root* which doesn't have the *private* ssh key for the *ansible* account so the *public-key authentication* fails when connecting to the remote node.

As you can see in your *ansible.cfg* you're connecting and executing as *ansible* on the remote nodes. I can't think of a reason why you would need to run Ansible commands locally (on the master node) as root, but you probably want to execute the ansible code remotely as root. As answered previously you should use the `become` option which will *sudo on the remote side*. Having "*PermitRootLogin yes*" in the sshd_config doesn't have any effect because Ansible is configured to use the *ansible* account to connect remotely, not *root*. (Which is also better for security reasons!)

Now.. you already have a working setup, but if you really need to run Ansible commands locally as *root*, or more likely, as a *regular* (e.g. your own) *user* (which is more often the case with multiple admins), in either case you would probably want to copy the private ssh key from the *ansible* account to your local ~/.ssh/ for this so you can login using public key authentication to your remote nodes.

You can for example point to this private key copy in the vars section of your inventory file:

```
[myhostgroup]
myhost1.remote
#...etc...

[myhostgroup:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_user=ansible
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/id_rsa_ansible_priv_key
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't run ansible with sudo which is not recommended way. Run it with the `-b` option (that intent meaning is become that is same as `sudo` in Linux).

> ansible all -m ping -b